# three.js how to map a texture on mtl,obj file

Tags: javascript, three.js, mapping

i'm trying to map a png file on mtl,obj file

**Before mapping**

[image]

but after mapping, the mtl texture just disappear.

**After mapping**

[image]

what should I do ?
I'm not good at English. If you can't understand my question, please leave  a comment.

this is my code :

```
           var onProgress = function(xhr) {
           var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
           console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
        };


        var onError = function(xhr) {};

        THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());

        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
        loader.load("../img/ang.png", function(image) {

           texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;   
           texture.image = image;
           texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
           texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
           texture.offset.set(-3, -9.5);
           texture.repeat.set(13, 13);
           texture.needsUpdate = true;

        },onProgress,onError);

        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setPath('../models/');
        mtlLoader.load('nag-green.mtl', function(materials) {

           materials.preload();

           var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
           objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
           objLoader.setPath('../models/');
           objLoader.load('nag-green.obj', function(object) {

              object.traverse(function(child) {

                 if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.material.map = texture;
                 }
              });

              object.name = "object";
              object.position.y = 0;
              scene.add(object);

           }, onProgress, onError);
        });
```

---

what I want to do is to map 'ang.png' file over that t-shirts like this

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqhNW.png)

Thank you for your answer Radio, I tried that way but this is not what i want to do.

[give a name to material and map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tASqt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You've applied the same 'ang.png' texture to all child meshes. I think you need a conditional in the traverse function to apply the texture only to the part of the mesh that needs the texture.

The mtl should have applied a name to the material when it first loaded. For example, here I am pretending the material name is "torso". Your exporter from the original 3d editor will have given it some other name. In any case, you should be able to query the name in the conditional:

```
          object.traverse(function(child) {
             if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {         
                 if(child.material != undefined){
                    if(child.material.name=="torso"){
                      child.material.map = texture;
                    }
                 }
             }
          });
```